# Why am I getting a "duplicate symbol" error for my functions in C?

Tags: c, gcc

I have three C files, `main.c`, `function1.c`, and `function2.c`. I compile them using `gcc -o main main.c function1.c function2.c`. I have a helper function `helper()` defined in `function1.c`. So `function1.c` looks like this:

```
void helper();

void function() {
...
}

void helper() {
...
}
```

However, when I try to define `helper()` the same way in `function2.c`, it gives me the error "`duplicate symbol '_helper'`". I assume this is because I've compiled `function1.c` and `function2.c` together, so `function2.c` is aware of the definition of `helper()` in `function1.c`, but I can't call `helper()` in `function2.c`. I also don't want to define `helper()` in its own file because I may end up writing many such helper files. What would be ideal is if I could have a `helper.c` file that contained functions `helper1()`, `helper2()`, etc, all accessible from `function1.c` and `function2.c`. Does anyone know how to do that, or a better alternative?

Comment: Add the `static` keyword to the function declaration and definition to limit the scope of the function to the file. Without the `static` keyword, the function identifier is in the global namespace.

Comment: This does solve the problem, thanks! Do you know how I can put all the helper functions in one method so that I don't have to re-declare them in each file?

Comment: C doesn't have methods, it only has functions.  But to explain your original problem, having the same function name in multiple source files does not affect compilation, it affects linking.  When you link multiple object files together, it resolves all global names.  That's how you can call a function in one file from a function in another.  Adding the `static` keyword makes a function local to the file, so it cannot be called directly from outside the file, but it also won't generate name conflicts when linking with other files.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to implement the same function twice

Just implement it in `function1.c`

```
void helper() {
...
}
```

In `function2.c` just declare it without implementation

```
extern void helper();
```

Comment: `extern` is for variables, not for functions. The function would just be declared `void helper(void);`. Note the `void` as argument to tell the compiler no arguments can be passed in. Ideally you'd put that declaration in a header file, and import that header file in both the file that defines the function (the implementation) and all files that use the function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Wrong, it can be used for both. `extern` is also often used for functions, see [example](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498/pthreads/pthread.c)

Comment: *Technically* you can add `extern` to a function, but function scope is global by default, so it's meaningless. It's just noise, therefore better left off.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I know it doesn’t change the behavior, but I personally do it and a lot of other people do it, to have a better overview by seeing instantly what functions are implemented in different files